# py-opencv import error in Bash for Windows 10

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10

I installed `py-opencv` in Bash for Windows 10 using Anaconda:

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

But when I import it in my Python3 interpreter, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libopencv_reg.so.3.1: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument
```

It works fine on my Ubuntu machine so I figure this is a bug with Bash for Windows 10. If anyone has a work around it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have already found a solution, given the time that passed since you asked the question.

I faced the same problem and the solution in my case was installing `opencv-python`, which makes the bindings between OpenCV and Python. To install use the command `sudo pip install opencv-python`.

Works in the latest Windows build.